# ApplicationIdleDetectionMode and WebBrowser functionality in WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8, browser

In WP8, if we set

```
ApplicationIdleDetectionMode = IdleDetectionMode.Disabled
```

the app continues to run even when the screen is locked.

If, for instance, we have a WebBrowser in an app (which is actually active only when the app is in the foreground), and the above property is set as disabled:

- Will the WebBrowser continue its execution even when the screen is locked (for example, playing an audio file).
- Will the WebBrowser continue its execution even when the app is switched to the background.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As for running under lock screen - yes it should run, you can get more information from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff941090%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

As I have tested once, WebBrowser is using BackgroundAudio to play (audio element), so it should also play under lock screen and probably in background (thought you should test it).

When the App goes to dormant state - all its processes are stopped [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff817008%28v=vs.105%29.aspx):

> When the user navigates forward, away from an app, after the Deactivated event is raised, the operating system will attempt to put the app into a dormant state. In this state, all of the application’s threads are stopped and no processing takes place, but the application remains intact in memory.

You should also watch out for [Certification requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh184838%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), when usind AppIdleDetection - point 6.3 – Apps running under a locked screen.